# CI 3 operation for user auth w/out model file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've revised my code after following tutorials, but I'm still stuck and would appreciate some guidance on how to fix by just using the view and controller.

View:

```
 <form name='checkLogin' action='<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/myform/checkLogin' method='post'>
  <input type="text" name='username' id='username' class="form-control" placeholder="Username" style='height: 3em;'><br>
  <input type="password" name='password' id='password' class="form-control" style='height: 3em;' placeholder="Password" required><br>
  <center><button class="btn draw-border" type="submit" >Sign in</button></center>
  <center><br><a href= "/ci/index.php/myform/<?php echo "userRegistration";?>">Register</a></center>
 </form>
```

Controller:

```
public function showLogin(){

    $this->load->view('loginview');

}   

// check login data 

public function checkLogin() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|callback_check_database');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('loginview');
        } else {
            redirect("/myform/successmessage");
        }
}

public function check_database($user_password){
    $user = $this->input->post('username');
    $pass = $this->input->post('password');

    $result = $this->user->login($user, $pass);

    if ($result) {
        $query = array();
        foreach($result as $row) {
            $query = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'username' => $row->user_name
            );
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
        return false; 
    }

}
```

The names of my two table rows, besides id, in MySQL, are `'user_name'` and `'user_password'`.

Comment: Without the controller or without the model?

Comment: It's really hard to know what you're actually asking. Please clarify.

Comment: you can easily access database in controller too, using `$this->db`.

Comment: This may help old tutorial but will get you started https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmKm1gCgUoM&list=PL161C7E0E6A01B1E0

Comment: i have been trying out methods for database interaction without the model. i want all DB queries to derive from controller functions. the youtube tutorial should help, but does anyone have an idea of how to incorporate what would be model code into my controller?

Comment: please see my revised code above